# How to show a string graph with '\n' in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to show a string graph with '\n' in dataframe, but i found it show '\n' instead of line feed.
please see the following:

```
# i have two string
an='*'
s1 = ' %s\n%s \n%s%s' % (an, an, an, an)  # this is a string graph
s2 = '%s%s\n %s\n%s ' % (an, an, an, an)
```

print it to get the string graph

print(s1):

```
 *
* 
**
```

and print(s2):

```
**
 *
*
```

but if i put them into a series, it miss the format

```
s=pd.Series([s1, s2])
print(s)
```

here is the result

```
0     *\n* \n**
1    **\n *\n* 
dtype: object
```

I want to show the string graph when print(df)
Is there any methods i can use to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using lists instead of a Series?  I suppose the proper question is: Why have you determined a Series is the appropriate data structure?

Comment: @S3DEV actually, i want to show string graph in my pandas dataframe, which i think series is similar with dataframe. so i use it as example. I dont think list is good, since i want to show data with a lot of columns

Comment: Fair play.  To help clarify, in basic terms, a Series is essentially a single column in a DataFrame.  Series: 1 column, DataFrame: A collection of Series.

Comment: What is the expected output when printing the series?

Comment: @deecue in the grid, string should have several line, not one line with '\n', same with print() result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in the grid, string should have several line, not one line with '\n', same with print() result.

I believe the Series is printing out the correct representation of the data. `\n` appears in the Series to show that the row contains a new line `\n` character.

To actually print a new line into the console, you can iterate each row in the series:

```py
for index, value in s.iteritems():
   print(index, value)
```

gives out

```
0  *
*
**
1 **
 *
*
```

Answer (score -1):

print(s.to_string().replace("\\n", "\n\t"))

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some elaboration to your answer.

Comment: This link will be helpful https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.3/pandas/core/series.py#L1297-L1402

Comment: While the linked material may answer the question, it’s better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link only for reference. Links can become invalid.

Comment: Thx, i think it works. to_string works for Series, but failed in dataframe. at least, i know how to make it show correct - just format the string by myself, but i think it's inconvenient. Thx a lot

Comment: welcome, print(s) is same as print(s.__repr__()) and func to_string() in func __repr__()